# Where to draw the bounded context line, in a modular monolith?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

So this is the case, it is a simple factory spare parts software. Consisting of following bounded contexts all located in their own module assembly following clean architecture.

Everything is exposed through a rest api.

- **Accounts**
  handles authentication and other account things
- **SpareParts**
  contains repository of different spare parts, organised in categories. There are also some rules regarding naming and multi language support
- **Inspections**
  A user can create a new inspection and can add what spare parts where used.

My question is, how can I select parts and add them to the inspection object? Do I have to keep a copy of all parts including language ect. or should they not be treated as separate context?
Or have some other design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, each service / module should be autonomous.  In other words, it should have all of the information and business logic it needs to do its job.

So, you have 2 relevant contexts:  "Spare Parts Inventory" & "Inspections".

I presume that your spare parts inventory is something that will include lots of searchable information about the parts.  Perhaps it contains all of the information required to print a catalog for customers to browse.

For the Inspections context, imagine you are writing out an Inspection Sheet on paper, manually.  What information about the spare parts do you need to represent on that sheet?

I'm going to assume that it's just the part number, name and quantity.

In which case, to keep Inspections context autonomous, it should have *JUST* that information readily available, not the whole spart parts object data as stored in the inventory.

How to synchronise?

One option is that in all of your API's that the client uses when creating spare parts, deleting spare parts, or changing the name of a spare part, then after sending command to the Spare Parts Inventory context, it then sends command to the Inspections context with a subset of the data to keep the data synchronised in Inspections context.

A more sustainable way, is for the Spare Parts context to publish events when a part is created, deleted or renamed.

The Inspections context can then listen for those events and update its local store accordingly.  You can either publish events with just enough information to keep the consumer of the event happy (i.e. part number and name), or just publish the Id and let the infrastructure of the Inspections context make a call back to the Inventory API to get the relevant details before performing updates in the local Inspections domain.

Using events between the bounded contexts prevents leakage of domain knowledge into the API, but, as mentioned in another answer, collecting information in the API from one context before talking the next context is a shortcut.  But is something that would likely bite you later down the line if your solution grows in complexity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A design issue right now that I am struggling with is that The Inspections module needs to display more info about a spare part and to add complexity it needs to do that in multiple languages (not at the same time though). It kind of makes me wonder if then I need to keep a complete copy of a SparePart Entity inside the Inspections Context. On the other hand the language is a "Infrastrucure" concern

Comment: @dzed For 'display' use a query that gets data from a third context (data-warehouse) or queries each of your 2 BCs and consolidates data for user view.  But, if that extra info is not required for the 'behaviour' of maintaining inspections, then don't copy that data there.  Arguably, inspections BC could perform its behaviour just using the ID of the spare part; it depends on whether the behaviour of inspections are influenced by other props of the spare part.  Personally, I like to copy name into other BCs, even if redundant,  as it can help with debugging.  Hard to know with just id.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me, also like the debug aspect of keeping the name. To satisfy the need of the View i could expose both  BCs (Read Models) through say a specific REST Api or even GraphQL. Both BCs data is stored in same database though they are separated by their own schema. Would you say that then a third context would be a better approach than having BCs expose their read data individually and then aggregated by a separate API? Thank you for your response really appreciate it.

Comment: Whether to create a 'warehouse' context really comes down to needs.  If you don't need it, don't bother.  You'll be creating a layer that the client communicates with to get the view so if you decide you want to create a warehouse later instead of aggregating from two separate BCs, that will have zero impact on the client.  If you expect heavy volume of reads that will be hitting the same tables as the contexts use for processing commands, then there's an argument for separation.  My approach would be:  wait until it is apparent that it's needed.

Comment: Thank you i am marking this post as the answer due the reasoning and pragmatic approach to the problem I am struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

If you are splitting your application in bounded contexts, regardless of how you implement it (monolith or separate services), the critical part of the design is to decide what information goes into what bounded context. If you find that you need to duplicate information in different contexts or a context needs to get information from another context to perform its job, then it's a sign that your boundaries could be incorrect.

That said, it is normal that you have a bounded context that produces some concepts and gives them an Id and another context keeps a reference of these Ids to operate with them. In your scenario, the SpareParts context is in charge of registering new Parts (and giving them a unique Id). No other context in your application can create a Part. But your Inspection context is allowed to store a reference to the parts every time it sees a "PartRegisteredEvent".

Effectively, both the SpareParts and the Inspections context will have a list of Parts with the same Ids, but:

1. only the SpareParts context can Register and Deregister (or any better names that your domain experts use)
2. the information relating to Parts stored in each context will be different. For example, in the SpareParts context, you'll have the Name, translations, images, etc. In the Inspections context, you'll have any information needed to use the parts in the inspections. You can eventually have an Inventory context with a list of parts and their stock quantities, and another context with the list of parts and their prices.

Normally the next questions are:

1. How can I show all the information of a Part to a user in a single screen? The answer is view or data composition. Either compose your views with "widgets" which get data from their corresponding context or have the API fetch the data from each context and construct a single response object.
2. How can each bounded context collect the information that they need? there are two ways: a) using events: PartRegistered, PartUnregistered, etc. b) the reverse approach from point 1: either have different widgets talk to different bounded contexts, or decompose a request in the API to send the data to the corresponding bounded context.

Bonus approach: there is a shortcut that works relatively well in monoliths to avoid maintaining the list of Parts in each bounded context using events. In your scenario, when the API receives a request to add part X to an inspection Y, instead of sending the request directly to the Inspections BC, which requires that Inspections knows that part X exists, you can do a precheck right at the API level that validates in SpareParts that part X exists if it exists, it then forwards the request to Inspections. If Inspections didn't know about Part X, it can create a record for it. With this approach, BCs can always trust that the data they receive is valid because it has been validated at the API level. But note that if you translate this approach into microservices, it'll introduce at least one extra roundtrip to a microservice per request.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a monolith, right? If yes, then you've at least 2 options.

You can follow the purist approach, hence you have a copy of all the relevant information of one domain in another domain. The copy is done using the rest api, because its the way the three domains expose themselves to the outside. When perform this copy is also a question, with this approach.
Do you need to communicate each change? Then you need a kind of even bus (external) that notifies every chance. You need also a way to manage inconsistencies, due to actions performed using old information.

Another approach is to implement, inside the infrastructure layer (you use a the clean architecture, so it's not going to pollute anyway the domain), the management of the information that comes from another domain. There you'll use the queries, or any other code that you've inside the infrastructure layer of another domain, to present the information inside the current domain. To put it simple, you allow to interact, at the infrastructure layer, two or more domains to avoid to implement all the code that otherwise you need using the rest api. Here you can also choose to get directly the information from the persistence without the need of copies of it.

Both are possible. With the first one, if in the future you need to split the project, the work is already done. But you pay the price of extra code. If you go for the second, you reuse inside the monolith what you've already implemented, without exposing anything more the the planned APIs. But, if in the future you need to split the code, you have to implement all the management of the communication between the domains.

It really depends on the future plans for the future. Anyway, I would suggest to keep the things simple. You can have a working system without not so much overhead, and plan the extra work if need in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for a pragmatic approach. When you say to to get data directly from the persistence of SpareParts. Do you then suggest that I should have a copy of the spare parts entity model inside the infrastructure layer of the Inspections or to reference the SpareParts Domain or Infra. layer?

Comment: "or to reference the SpareParts Domain or Infra. layer" ... Yes.  Make an API call to SpareParts from the Inspections infra to feed into the Inspections domain for processing.